# Как в Delphi добавлять произвольный файл в ресурс exe без пересоздания res?

Tags: delphi, resources

У меня есть js файл, который мне нужен в ресурсах. Как его добавить в ресурс программы что бы при изменении js ресурс обновлялся автоматически при новой компиляции?

Причем любой новых exe у которого будет подключен модуль загрузки uLoadScript.pas в котором есть `{$R 'script.res'}` должен на автомате брать последнюю версию js файла без добавления через интерфейс IDE нового ресурса.

[1й способ для этого подойдет или он будет старый файл загружать?](https://mirsovetov.net/delphi-res.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу конечно в константу превратить скрип но это не удобно и синтаксис js не будет поддерживаться + синтаксис делфи не удобный для много строк

Итог. после чтения https://habr.com/ru/post/550020/
1)Не понятно как применить что написано в статье ВООБЩЕ!
2) Мне нужна просто команда которая сама создаст новый res с rc и все. {R 'MyRc.rc' 'MyRes.res'} >> плз создай новый MyRes.res

Comment: В delphi есть же встроенный [менеджер ресурсов](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Resources_and_Images). С помощью него можно что угодно добавить в список ресурсов. В Rc-файле будет ссылка на скрипт, при каждом ребилде ресурсы будут обновляться. Никаких проблем. Во всяком случае, в 10.3 работало.

Comment: Прошу прощения, невнимательно прочитал вопрос. Если есть готовый rc, можно использовать компилятор ресурсов, прописав как шаг прекомпиляции. К сожалению, Delphi у меня сейчас нет, точные действия подсказать не могу.

Comment: А что, директива `{$R 'MyRc.res' 'MyRes.rc'}` и вправду не работает? [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153394/how-do-i-make-a-png-resource/1153532#1153532) похожий вопрос. Полагаю, нужно прописать необходимые (полные/относительные) пути к файлам.

Comment: @Old Skull   я дополнил вопрос и так и не понял зачем нужно {$R 'MyRc.res' 'MyRes.rc'} и что делает. у меня с ней ничего не работает

Comment: насколько я понимаю, `{$R 'MyRc.res' 'MyRes.rc'}` заставляет сборщик скомпилировать ресурс `MyRes.rc` в `MyRes.res` и подцепить получившийся файл к выходному `exe`. Именно так я не пробовал, но я подключал через `{$R 'Res\MyRc.res'}`, где `Res` - подпапка в папке проекта. А `res`-файл я компилировал отдельно. Почему? Даже не подумал, что так можно. Не знаю - допустимы ли абсолютные пути в директиве `{$R}`. Также вполне может оказаться, что достаточно просто `{$R 'Res\MyRc.rс'}`. Но, возможно, я [неправ](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Resource_file_(Delphi))

Comment: в хабровской статье приведён cmd-файл, в котором осуществляется компиляция rc-файла. Т.е. промежуточный шаг присутствует. Т.о., если Вы хотите полного автоматизма, то, видимо, придётся написать некий шаблонный командный файл и использовать его для сборки проектов. Или настраивать шаги прекомпиляции.

Comment: Мне тут ещё вариант подсказали: ресурсная dll. Все ваши проекты могут подгружать ресурсы из отдельной библиотеки. Преимущество такого подхода в том, что в случае необходимости нужно будет пересбрать только библиотеку, а не целый ворох проектов.

Answer (score 2):

1. Создать файл `script.rc` со следующим содержимым:

```
MYSCRIPTJS RCDATA script.js
```

2. Подключить его в файле проекта:

```
{$R 'script.res' 'script.rc'}
```

3. Выполнить **Build** (Shift + F9) проекта - будет автоматически создан файл ресурсов `script.res` и прилинкован к exe.

И каждый раз, когда вы изменяете содержимое своего `script.js`, вам нужно выполнять полный Build проекта, чтобы создавался новый `*.res` файл и обновлённое содержимое включалось в `*.exe` (при Compile подхватывается уже существующий `*.res` файл для ускорения сборки проекта).

Comment: при первом запуске не находит файл script.res но его же еше нет. его в ручную нужно создавать?

Comment: у меня не выходит так сделать. получается только если .rc я добавлю в файлы проекта. а с {$R 'script.res' 'script.rc'} в произвольном pas который подключен в Unit1 не получается пишет  не найден файл а если его создам то он не обновляется Мб это зависит от настроек компилятора?